# XNA server client model

Tags: xna, client-server

Hi what is the best model for creating client server application in one solution in xna, client as xna application, server as console and model as reference added to client and server? or maybe one xna application with global variable isHost passed from separate client/ server application running this xna application, or mayby different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add multiple projects to your solution in Visual Studio. One will be the XNA game, and one will be a console application or class library that will be referenced by the XNA game project.

Also, [here](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/network_cs) is a sample of how to make a client/server architecture.